# Installing Olark in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have JavaScript code from Olark that requires you to add to the HTML body somewhere.

I added the JavaScript code to assets/javascript/olark.js and appended a require olark.js to application.js

Nothing happens in my app. What else do I need to do to make Olark appear?

Comment: Have you viewed the rendered source to verify whether or not `olark.js` is indeed being loaded?

Comment: Yes, 3189389:Started GET "/assets/olark.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-28 20:37:01 -0400
3189390:Served asset /olark.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)

Comment: Are you using turbolinks?

Comment: No I am not. Should the setup I have above work with olark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code that olark provides you there are some HTML tags. Remove the HTML tags and it should work.

Here is my setup:

app/assets/javascripts/application.js

`//= require olark`

app/assets/javascripts/olark.js

`...olark code they provide when you sign up without html`

Comment: I would place this file in `vendor/assets/javascripts` instead since this is javascript was written by a 3rd party.  No change is needed in application.js.

Comment: Good if you want olark across your entire site.  @Sung Won Cho 's answer (above) is better IMO if using on only a few pages.  Also, check out the rack-olark gem written by a former olark employee

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that with turbolink activated, when I clic on an internal link, the chat widget is no longer available.
I think that I can use the same tip of this topic on [Google Analytics with Rails issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126060/google-analytics-not-showing-correct-active-page-in-rails-app). If someone have a tip on that? ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative solution to the accepted answer by @Bruno.

You can put the code snippet into a partial, and render it in your view.

This feels neater to me because you do not need to manually remove html codes. You can use the code snippet as provided without any modification.