# Google Analytics Not Showing Correct Active Page in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-analytics

I have a Rails 4 App with the Google Analytics js right before the end of the `body` to work with Turbolinks. However, unless I specifically reload the page I'm on, the Active Page always shows up as '/'. Is there any way to correct this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [google-analytics-turbolinks gem](https://github.com/shukydvir/google-analytics-turbolinks) and add the script as usual.

**Update:**

The only thing the gem does, is that it adds this coffeescript file into the assets folder:

```
if window.history?.pushState and window.history.replaceState
  document.addEventListener 'page:change', (event) =>

    # Google Analytics
    if window.ga != undefined
      ga('set', 'location', location.href.split('#')[0])
      ga('send', 'pageview', {"title": document.title})
    else if window._gaq != undefined
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview'])
    else if window.pageTracker != undefined
      pageTracker._trackPageview();
```

Comment: Thanks. I went ahead and used it. I just prefer knowing how to do it myself. I'll dig through the source when I have a chance.